# ¿Cómo cuento y guardo los valores diferentes que aparecen en una columna?

Tags: python

Estoy creando un script en python que indique los nombres de los diferentes shells asignados a las cuentas de usuario en el archivo /etc/passwd y la cantidad de cuentas de cada uno de esos shells.

Para ello, he creado un array que me de todos los valores del campo. Pero aquí esta el problema, ahora tengo que sacar por pantalla todos los shells sin que se repitan y los repetidos contar a cuantos usuarios están asignados. La verdad, después de probar diferentes maneras no se me ocurre como hacerlo. Adjunto el código que me da los valores del array:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
shells = []
with open("/etc/passwd", "r") as passwords:
    for linea in passwords:
        shell = linea.split(":")[6]
        shells.append(shell)
print(shells)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Todo lo que te falta hacer es preguntar si el `shell` está ya en `shells`, y agregarlo sólo en caso que no esté.

Además, como quieres contar las repeticiones, mejor usar un diccionario usando el nombre del shell como llave y las repeticiones como valor:

```
shells = {}
with open("/etc/passwd", "r") as passwords:
    for linea in passwords:
        shell = linea.split(":")[6].strip()
        if shell not in shells:
            shells[shell] = 1
        else:
            shells[shell] += 1

print(shells)
```

produce:

```
{'/bin/bash': 3, '/usr/sbin/nologin': 39, '/bin/sync': 1, '/bin/false': 4}

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Bien el primer punto, resuelto, gracias, el tema es ahora como contar los usuarios asignados

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar un `defaultdict` para ir guardando en un diccionario una lista de nombres asociada a cada shell:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

count = defaultdict(list)

with open('/etc/passwd') as p:
   for linea in p:
      if linea.startswith('#'):
         continue
     shell = linea.split(':')[6].strip()
     name = linea.split(':')[0].strip()
     count[shell].append(name)
```

Y luego cuentas cuántos y ves cuáles iterando sobre `count`:

```
for shell, users in count.items():
    print(f'{shell} --> {len(users)}: {users}')
```

Answer (score 1):

Usa la clase [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). Esta clase recibe como argumento un iterable, y captura el número de repeticiones de cada elemento.

Para acceder al número de repeticiones de cada elemento, solo accede a `frequencys[element]`, donde `element` es la cadena, entero, objeto, etc, que quieres saber su frequencia. En caso de intentar acceder a la frecuencia de un elemento que no estaba en el iterable, el objeto `frequencys` va retornar un valor de 0.

```py
from collections import Counter

def extract_shell_name(line):
    return line.split(':')[-1].strip()


frequencys = None

with open('/etc/passwd', mode='r') as fp:
        frequencys = Counter(map(extract_shell_name, fp.readlines()))
```

Nota que en la función `extract_shell_name` no se hizo referencia al campo con índice 6, en su lugar se hizo referencia al campo `-1`, es decir al último campo de la lista. Esto genera menos ambiguedad al valor semántico del índice y da un mensaje más claro de que el campo de interés es el último.

**Extra.**
Si estas en linux (que es lo más seguro), puedes utilizar un pipeline de comandos que ya se encuentran disponibles en casi todas las distribuciones (si no es que en todas), para obtener el mismo resultado:

```sh
cat /etc/passwd | awk -F':' '{ print $NF }' | sort | uniq -c
```